# How to update a single column of all rows with the values of two columns on the same row?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with four columns:

```
col 1  | Col 2  | Col3 | Col4
-----------------------------
 a1       b1        c1    d1
 a2       b2        c2    d2
```

and so on, with many such rows.

Now, I want to have an SQL update statement where I can change the values on col3 of this table, for all the rows, so that:

- For row 1 the value in column 3 becomes  "a1 b1"
- For row 2 the value in column 3 becomes  "a2 b2"

and thus updates the entire table similarly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the first 2 fields concatenated into the 3rd field, try this:

```
update table set col3 = CONCAT(col1, ' ', col2);
```